# How to connect to AWS RDS with php?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, amazon-rds

Can't connect to RDS with PHP. I have a simple script:

```
<?php

define('DB_SERVER', 'rdsendPointName:3306');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'actualusername');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'passwordThatISetforRDS');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'RDSinstancenamehere');
echo "hello"
  /* Connect to MySQL and select the database. */
  $connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);

  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();

?>
```

The php file is placed in the www/html folder. I can open the browser and get to the php page but then I get the connection error.

```
Failed to connect to MySQL: Unknown MySQL server host
```

Security group: I have opened the port 3306 and all tcp port but still no luck.

I run the php file from the ec2 instance itself and the result is the same.

It can't get any simpler than this. All I have is a php file, the RDS instance is running (at least that is what I can see from the aws console).

Comment: I am sure if you looked at the documentation it would be in there somewhere near the top

Comment: I have tried everything, opened all the ports and still no luck

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_PHP.rds.html#php-rds-connect

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_PHP.rds.html

Comment: How do I test if connection is successfull with: <?php
$dbhost = $_SERVER['RDS_HOSTNAME'];
$dbport = $_SERVER['RDS_PORT'];
$dbname = $_SERVER['RDS_DB_NAME'];
$charset = 'utf8' ;

$dsn = "mysql:host={$dbhost};port={$dbport};dbname={$dbname};charset={$charset}";
$username = $_SERVER['RDS_USERNAME'];
$password = $_SERVER['RDS_PASSWORD'];

$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
?>

Comment: Look for the error message that your code throws if the connection fails

Comment: Updated php version to php 7 and now I dont get connection error but rather: Error creating table.

Error adding employee data.

Comment: is RDS in VPC or classic mode ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for mysqli_connect, the first parameter should be the hostname, and there are optional parameters if you want to specify a non-standard port.

So if you remove the :3306 from the DB_SERVER value, it should work.

Comment: Not sure if it is connecting or not. Will update the question to show the entire script.